# Will the rods rotate about the hinge after collision?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

[image]

The problem is like this: **two blocks**(considered to be point masses) of masses $m$ are simultaneously moving with uniform velocities $v_0$ towards the rods and they hit the edges of rod and stick to it(i.e, perfectly inelastic collision). Each of the rods have a mass $m$(same as the blocks) and have length $l$. They are hinged together in the middle by a friction less hinge. Find the velocity of the hinge just after collision and the angular velocities of the rods about the hinge.

My approach:

Let the vel. of the hinge after collision be $v$. Then by conservation of linear momentum, $$mv_0 + mv_0 = 4mv \Rightarrow v= v_0/2$$ 
**Note**: I believe that the centre of mass of the system(two rods and the blocks sticked  to them) is at the hinge just after collision.
[image]

Let the angular velocity of the rods about the hinge be $\dot\theta$ 
Now, let us consider the angular momentum of the system abot point $P$.
$$2lmv_0=0+2l \cdot m \cdot(v_0/2+\dot\theta l)+ \frac{3l}{2} \cdot m \cdot(v_0/2+\dot\theta \frac{l}{2}) + \frac{ml^2}{12} \cdot \dot{\theta} + \frac{l}{2} \cdot m \cdot(v_0/2+\dot\theta \frac{l}{2}) - \frac{ml^2}{12} \cdot \dot{\theta}$$

On solving, we get $\dot{\theta}=0$

So, according to my equations, the angular velocity is **zero**.
Are my calculations oK? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have no idea why people gave `close vote` ? It's a problem of dynamical system. I want to give a `reopen vote` vote in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linear momentum calculation is pre-supposing that the entire system moves as a rigid body post-impact.

But each of the two hinged pieces could be rotating about the hinge (so that the overall system is not rigid). The center of mass of each piece is distance $\frac{3}{4}l$ from the hinge, so that balance of linear momentum gives
$$2mv_0 = 4m\left(v + \frac{3}{4}l\dot\theta\right)$$
rather than just $4mv$ on the RHS.

Comment: ok, but, just after the collision, will the COM of  the system not be at the hinge?

Comment: Ok, so, if this is one equation, I need another one in order to find values of both $v$ and $\dot{\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

The total angular momentum about the hinge is $0$ by symmetry, but that does not mean the rods are not rotating about the hinge.  It just means the rods are rotating at the same speed in opposite directions.  You can figure the rotation rate by considering the angular momentum of one rod+block about the hinge.  There is no torque around the hinge, so you can consider one side in isolation for this.  Just before the collision it is $mv_0l$.  The moment of inertia of a rod+block is $\frac 43ml^2$.  If we define $\phi$ as the angle of either rod with respect to the horizontal, but measured clockwise on the right and counterclockwise on the left, the angular momentum of one side is $\frac 43ml^2\dot \phi$  This gives $\dot \phi = \frac {3v_0}{4l}$

So after the impact the center of mass is moving at $\frac 12v_0$ upward and both rod+blocks are rotating upward around the hinge at $\dot \phi = \frac {3v_0}{4l}$. The center of mass is on the center line at $\frac 34$ of the way along the rods.

Comment: The total angular momentum about P is never zero.

Comment: The initial angular momentum about P is $(m\cdot v_0)\cdot 2l$. This is actually the angular mom. of the farther block because for the closer block it is $0$

Comment: I thought $P$ was the pivot.  The angular momentum of the system is zero about that because the two blocks balance out.  You are right that if $P$ is the end of one rod the angular momentum is not zero.  That $P$ is not so useful as considering the hinge.

Comment: Sir please see the second image. P is just a point with the same horizontal position as the left block and an arbitrary vertical position.

Comment: Then you need to define two angular variables.  One is the angle of the left rod with respect to the horizontal and one is the angle of the right rod with respect to the horizontal.  You will have to use the translation theorem to find the angular momentum of the right rod with respect to $P$.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do the analysis around the hinge, which is a much easier point to work from.

Comment: I believe that your method is flawed. I will post something in a moment.

Comment: Yes. The point that moves at $\frac 12v_0$ is the CM, which is on the axis between the points $\frac 34$ of the way up the rods. The hinge will move irregularly